# Storage location of a struct used within a function

Tags: c

Let's say I have the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct Book {
    int year;
    char *title;

} Book;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Book myBook = {
        .year = 1990,
        .title ="Don and Jane"
    };
    printf("%s", myBook.title);
    printf("%p\n", &myBook.title);
    printf("%p", &myBook.year);
    return 0;

}
```

> Don and Jane 
> 0x7ffee17376e8 
> 0x7ffee17376e0

Where is the `Book` object stored? My thought is it would be stored as (assuming 0 is the local stack, and also ignoring the output of the program -- which I added in after):

- string `Don and Jane` <-- stored somewhere in rodata
- int `year` stored locally on the stack at -16 (?). (assume int=4 bytes)
- long/pointer `title` stored on the stack at -12.

So basically we have those 16 bytes (though it only takes up 12) stored locally on the stack, even though the string-pointer refers to a non-stack memory address. is that more-or-less accurate, or am I missing/incorrect in anything? Are the elements of a struct stored like an array, opposite that, or can be anything and not defined in the language?

Comment: The C standard doesn't dictate where. Are you asking about a particular compiler?

Comment: @tadman nope -- just generally if my understanding of local storage is ok. But the compiler I'm using is `gcc` but I'm not concerned about a particular compiler.

Comment: There will probably be padding bytes between `year` and `title` on a 64-bit system (which is also why the size is 16, not 12).  This is confirmed by the difference of 8 between the address of `year` and the address of `title` in the printing.  You should be casting the pointers printed with `%p` to `(void *)` as `%p` expects a `void *`.

Comment: Basically, the structure is stored on the stack, and the pointer points to memory elsewhere.

Comment: If you keep just the first `printf` chances are there won't be a struct stored anywhere, just a `printf` call with two constant string addresses as arguments. Assuming the struct *is* stored somewhere, its fields must be in the order of definition, with the necessary padding inserted. While it would normally be on the stack, there is nothing in this particular code that would prevent a playful compiler from assigning it static read-only storage if it so wished.

Comment: @dxiv when you say 'static' storage do you mean somewhere in `data` or in a `register` or what do you mean by that?

Comment: @David542 Memory for sure, not register, since you are taking addresses of members.

Comment: @dxiv oh right, got it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Each compiler is free to organize this however they see fit, so it's a relevant question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why is it necessary to do `(void *)` in this case? Does it automatically cast to that otherwise, or why is specifying that better than not?

Comment: As I said, `%p` expects to be passed a `void *`.  When you pass `&myBook.title`, you pass a ` char **`; when you pass `&myBook.year`, you pass an `int *`.  Neither of those is a `void *`.  In practice, it seldom matters, but there could be (obscure) machines where it makes a difference.  (I learned C on a machine where it would have mattered, but said machine is at best a museum piece.  It was wonderful when we got the main memory upgraded from 1 MiB to 2 MiB — which tells you something about how long ago that was.)